# I'm getting an error trying to access a map in a class method declared as const

Tags: c++, dictionary, constants

Below is a simplified version of something I am trying to do.

I am getting a C2678 error on the return line of `getMove2()`. The only difference between `getMove()` and `getMove2()` is `const`.

I have a work-around (commented-out line), but I'm trying to understand why that line doesn't work, and how else to fix it.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Dummy
{
public:
    Dummy(std::string character, int a, int b, int c) {
        name = character;

        moves["a"] = a;
        moves["b"] = b;
        moves["c"] = c;
    }

    int getMove(std::string move_name) {
        return moves[move_name];
    }

    int getMove2(std::string move_name) const {
        return moves[move_name];
        //return moves.find(move_name)->second; //This works but I can't figure out how to make the above work
    }
private:
    std::string name;
    std::map <std::string, int> moves;
};
```

I have tried playing around with having different pieces of the `map` as `const`, but no luck.

Comment: the error code is close to meaningless. You should read teh compiler error message. It should tell you what is wrong. If you do not understand  it, no problem, others can explain it if you include it in the question

Comment: in the constructor you use `moves["a"] = a;` where `[]` modifies the map. `operator[]` is non-const.

Comment: `moves[move_name];` potentionally changes your map member, and that's not possible for a `const` class instance of `Dummy`.

Comment: using `find` is perfectly fine to find an element in a map, though you need to handle the case when the element cannot be found

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: Additional suggestion: use an initializer list in your constructor. E.g. `Dummy(std::string character, int a, int b, int c) : name(character), moves{{"a", a}, {"b", b}, {"c", c}} { }`

Comment: `moves[move_name]` adds `move_name` to the map if it's not present. Hence the method is not `const`. It's one of those "wtf" things about the C++ standard library. Probably seemed like a good idea at the time. C++20 has a decent fix. Rather unbelievable we had to wait that long. Have a sympathetic upvote!

Answer (score 2):

The class template `std::map` declares the following methods to access individual elements by key:

```
T& operator[](key_type&& x);
T& operator[](key_type&& x);
T& at(const key_type& x);
const T& at(const key_type& x) const;
```

As you can see, both subscript operators are not declared as `const` methods, so you may not call them on a `const` `std::map` object.  Since `getMove2()` is declared as `const`, its `this` pointer has the type `Dummy const *`, and so the `moves` member is `const` when accessed through that pointer.

However, you can call the `map::at()` method which is declared as `const`.

For example:

```
int getMove2(std::string move_name) const {
    return moves.at( move_name );
}
```

Comment: Just note that `map::at()` will throw an exception if the specified key does not exist. If you want to return a default value in that case, use `map::find()` instead and check its result, eg: `int getMove2(std::string move_name) const { auto iter = moves.find(move_name); return (iter != moves.end()) ? iter->second : 0; }`